# Two Solutions for Limiting Distribution of Transformed Exponential RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I have a problem that I am working on.  I have thought of two approaches, but they are giving me different answers.  I wanted to know which (or if each) approach was wrong and why.

**Prompt**: $X_1, X_2, ...$ are $\overset{iid}{\sim}Expo(1)$.  Let $X_{n:n}$ be an order statistic.  Define $Y_n = X_{n:n} - ln(n)$.  Show that $Y_n$ converges in law to a limit distribution as $n$ tends to infinity.

**Approach 1**:  Use properties of order statistics to find a distribution for $X_{n:n}$, then transfrom $X_{n:n}$ to $Y_n$

$$f_{X_{n:n}}(X_{n:n}=x) = n \left [ 1 - exp(-x)\right ]^{n-1}exp(-x)$$

Which gives us,

$$F_{Y_n}(Y_n=y) = \left [ 1-exp(-y)\right]^{n-1}exp(-y)$$

**Approach 2**: Use properties of order statistics and probabilities to derive $F_{Y_n}(y)$

$$F_{Y_n}(y) = P(Y_n \leq Y) = P(X_{n:n} - ln(n)\leq y)$$

$$=P(X_{n:n} \leq y + ln(n))$$

$$=\left [ P(X_1 \leq y +ln(n)) \right ]^n$$

$$=\left [ 1 - exp(-y -ln(n))\right ]^n$$

$$=\left [ 1 - \frac{exp(-y)}{n}\right ]^n$$

$$\Rightarrow \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} e^{-e^{-y}}$$

Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: I agree to your second approach. The first approach I couldn´t comprehend yet. My notation is $F_{Y_\infty}(y)=\large{e^{-e^{-y}}}$

Comment: Was it the first line or second?  I'd be happy to expand more, just want to know where, it is a lot to type lol

Comment: The first line. I don´t know how you obtain $f_{X_{n:n}}(X_{n:n}=x) = n \left [ 1 - exp(-x)\right ]^{n-1}exp(-x)$

Comment: The approach with the CDF is correct, but in the last line you should say $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{Y_n}(y)=\exp(-e^{-y})$ for all real $y$.